# Direct bijection between $C[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

By applying the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem one can state that there *exists* a 
bijection between $C[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$. But is it possible to *construct* a  bijection between $C[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i think the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem is constructive, does this help you? The result might be very complicated, however.

Comment: @supinf I know that Schroeder-Bernstein gives an existential proof, that's why I ask for a rather concrete one. Simply, I know there exists one, so I am trying to construct one such!!

Comment: what i meant: from reading the proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem you can maybe find a concrete function that is bijective - the proof is constructive afaik

Comment: Each continuous function on $[0,1]$ is determined by its values at the rationals. That gives you a bijection between $C[0,1]$ and sequences of real numbers. Each of the real numbers in one of those sequences can be turned into a sequence of rational numbers using any bijection you like from the reals to the set of sequences of rationals. Then, all you need to do is map sequences of sequences of rationals, to just sequences of rationals. Do this by the usual diagonal traveling.

Comment: I've added the "set-theory" tag because I think's it's relevant, but feel free to remove it if you disagree.

Comment: Any proof I know of the Bernstein-Cantor-Schoeder theorem either directly or with very little work produces an explicit bijection from any given pair of injections. There is an obvious injection from $[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$, so the question reduces to finding an explicit injection from $C[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Don't you want the italics around "construct" instead of "bijection"?

Comment: @PhilJones Please don't yell. Again: The proofs of the Bernstein-Cantor-Schoeder theorem are not existence arguments, they are constructive. They produce explicit bijections.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Well the link below says "An important feature of the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein theorem is that it does not rely on the axiom of choice. However, its various proofs are non-constructive, as they depend on the law of excluded middle."

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123482/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I am aware. I am not using the term "constructive" in a technical sense, and neither seems that to be the intention of the question.

Comment: @MariePierredeLeTetou You wrote "That gives you a bijection between $C[0,1]$ and sequences of real numbers. " Certainly not all such sequences. I can't tell what you're doing, building an injective map from $C[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R $ or do you actually claim to have bult a bijection from $C[0,1]$ onto $\mathbb R?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All proofs of the Bernstein-Cantor-Schroeder theorem that I know either directly or with very little work produce an explicit bijection from any given pair of injections.

There is an obvious injection from $[0,1]$
to $C[0,1]$ mapping each $t$ to the function constantly equal to $t$, so the question reduces to finding an explicit injection from $C[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$.

Here is an example:

Any $f\in C[0,1]$ is determined by its restriction to the rationals. Fix an explicit enumeration $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

The [simple continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of a real $x\in(0,1)$ has the form $1/(c^x_0+1/(c^x_1+\dots))$ where the $c_i$ are positive integers. It is unique unless $x$ is rational, in which case it has exactly two representations, that differ on their last term (this is essentially a matter of convention, and some presentations pick one from the beginning); pick the shortest one if that is the case. The sequence $(c^x_0,c^x_1,\dots)$ is infinite unless $x$ is rational, in which case we will extend it to an infinite sequence by setting $c^x_i=0$ for all $i$ past the last index where the sequence was defined.

Each real $r$ corresponds to a unique sequence $(b^r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of naturals as follows:

- $b^r_0$ is $1$ if $r=0$, it is $2$ if $r>0$, and it is $3$ if $r<0$.
- Let $b^r_1=\lfloor |r|\rfloor+1$.
- Let $r'=(|r|-\lfloor|r|\rfloor)/2$ if $|r|-\lfloor |r|\rfloor$ is in $(0,1)$, and let $0'$ and $1'$ be your favorite (distinct) irrationals in $(1/2,1)$. Now let $b^r_n=c^{r'}_{n-2}+1$ for all $n\ge2$.

The assignment $r\mapsto(b^r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an injection.

Fix an explicit bijection $\tau:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N\times\mathbb N$, denote $\tau(n)$ by $(\tau(n)_0,\tau(n)_1)$.

Assign to $f\in C[0,1]$ the following infinite sequence of positive integers $(d^f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$:

- $d^f_n=b^{f(a_{\tau(n)_0})}_{\tau(n)_1}$.

Since everything is explicit so far, note that from $d^f_n$ we can reconstruct all the values $f(a_n)$, $n\in\mathbb N$, and therefore $f$.

Finally, there is a unique irrational $y_f\in(0,1)$ whose simple continued fraction is $(d^f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. The map $f\mapsto y_f$ is an explicit injection.

The explicit bijection provided by your favorite explicit proof of the Bernstein-Cantor-Schroeder theorem and the two explicit injections specified above do the trick.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for understanding and learning your statements : "It is unique unless x is rational, in which case it has exactly two representations, that differ on their last term (this is essentially a matter of convention, and some presentations pick one from the beginning); pick the shortest one if that is the case"